# How should I interpret this equation?

Tags: interpretation

I got this equation by predicting grassland biomass growth from precipitation and soilnutrient. 
How can I convert it into original power function and how to interpret scientifically.

```
logNDVI <- 0.36 + 64.8*log(precipitation) + 0.9*(soilNutrient)

P <- 0.01; R2= 0.72 and residual standard error=0.45
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "original power function."  Do you mean that `logNDVI` is the logarithm of observed biomass growth and you wish to express the corresponding growth directly in terms of `precipitation` and `soilNutrient`??

Comment: I mean that how to convert this log transformed formula into the one without log with exp() function.

Comment: You can find a great many threads involving this subject here: please visit [this search link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log*+exp*+regression).